# Laravel - Table migration crror with unsigned primary key

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

Currently I have this migration in Laravel that is failing:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('site_permission_modules', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::drop('site_permission_modules');
}
```

The Error that is displayed is as follows:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table
>   'orgasystem.site_permission_modules' (errno: 150) (SQL: create table
>   `site_permission_modules` (`id` int unsigned not null auto_increment
>   primary key, `name` var     char(255) not null, `created_at` timestamp
>   null, `updated_at` timestamp null) default character set utf8 collate
>   utf8_unicode_ci)

I have a lot of other tables that are succeeding without any problem.

When I copy the SQL statement Laravel throws to MySQL it also fails, but as soon as I remove the unsigned keyword on the primary key it succeeds. See below for statements.

**Fails:**

```php
create table `site_permission_modules` (
    `id` int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, 
    `name` varchar(255) not null, 
    `created_at` timestamp null, 
    `updated_at` timestamp null) 
default character set utf8 collate utf8_unicode_ci;
```

**Succeeds:**

```
create table `site_permission_modules` (
    `id` int not null auto_increment primary key, 
    `name` varchar(255) not null, 
    `created_at` timestamp null, 
    `updated_at` timestamp null) 
default character set utf8 collate utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Does anyone know why this would happen?

Comment: your php and mysql version ?

Comment: Used your "failing" sql and it worked fine on my mysql. Maybe you should check your mysql versión.

Comment: Your "failing" SQL looks good and worked on my MySQL (version 5.6.26) too.

Comment: @Riaan you can check your mysql version using the following sql statement: `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%version%";`, also, look if you're using `innoDB`or `MyISAM` there are some subtle differenteces that could generate this problem

Comment: Okay yeah, could possibly be the mysql version, I am currently using mamp and I see it's still on 5.5. I will check if it runs on my newer version at home and confirm here.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the answer was that the MySQL version was too low, while running MAMP on MySQL version 5.5 the migration wasn't working. I have tested the migration on version 5.7 and it successfully runs through all the migrations.

This does however confuse me a bit since I have done other Laravel migrations while still working on the same version of MAMP.

This may be something with the engine MySQL defaults to on the machine I was testing on first, unfortunately I cannot test it at the moment.